# SQuirreL Simplicit vjdbc VirtualDriver java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jdbc, mariadb, squirrel-sql

Using SQuirreL to connect/consult a distributed MariaDB, I get a `java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException` after every query execution. It arises even on `SHOW tables FROM catalog_name;` or the `SHOW columns FROM table_name;` kind of query. Is it common behaviour for this driver o do I have something wrong?

The error shows in its own result "Error" tab, right after the tab with the result I want. So far, it is just a matter of dismissing it (Ctrl+Shift+F4), so it is a minor annoyance, since the other result tab generated shows the good data. But I wonder if it is a symptom of something else that is wrong (installation, version co-ordination, ...): seeing a stack trace, in red, every time raises some flag in the back of my mind, even if I know I have the result right behind the red text.

I'm using Simplicit's vjdbc driver `de.simplicit.vjdbc.VirtualDriver.class` for the connection to the distributed MariaDB. Other drivers (DB2) in the same SQuirreL instance do not show the error. The vjdbc driver version is 1.6.5. (from 2007) and there is no later version, and I do not have access to the clear code on this installation.

The JVM is 1.7.0_40:

```
C:\Users\manuelvigarcia>java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

also as listed in the SQuirreL "about":

```
sun.boot.library.path   c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\bin
java.vm.version         24.0-b56
```

and SQuirreL version is 3.6

I assume that the error is produced in the Simplicit VirtualDriver, given the top of the exception stack trace, but I don't have access to the code.

Finally, I'll show the query:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, country_id FROM appartment_master.studio
WHERE appartment_id = 3000;
```

Resulting in a correct results pane:

```
latitude    longitude   country_id
12.59565    38.76614    11
```

And the error pane with the exception stack trace:

```
Error: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.serial.StreamingResultSet.populate(StreamingResultSet.java:141)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.command.ConnectionEntry.handleResultSet(ConnectionEntry.java:337)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.command.ConnectionEntry.executeCommand(ConnectionEntry.java:223)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.command.CommandProcessor.process(CommandProcessor.java:169)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.rmi.CommandSinkRmiImpl.process(CommandSinkRmiImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.util.SQLExceptionHelper.wrapThrowable(SQLExceptionHelper.java:59)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.util.SQLExceptionHelper.wrap(SQLExceptionHelper.java:17)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.command.CommandProcessor.process(CommandProcessor.java:180)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.server.rmi.CommandSinkRmiImpl.process(CommandSinkRmiImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.process(Unknown Source)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.rmi.CommandSinkRmiProxy.process(CommandSinkRmiProxy.java:40)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.command.DecoratedCommandSink.process(DecoratedCommandSink.java:69)
    at de.simplicit.vjdbc.VirtualStatement.getResultSet(VirtualStatement.java:150)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.StatementWrapper.getResultSetWrapper(StatementWrapper.java:101)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.SQLExecuterTask.processQuery(SQLExecuterTask.java:398)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.SQLExecuterTask.run(SQLExecuterTask.java:212)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.util.TaskExecuter.run(TaskExecuter.java:82)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 0
```

Comment: Let's see a sample query and the Java code that tries to execute it.

Comment: Added the query and the result within the question. There is no Java code: I'm querying the DB from SQuirreL GUI.